# Rack::Cache with redis not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, redis, rack

I am trying to setup my Rack::Cache to work with dragonfly. I want to have a shared redis cache on a separate server so that the cache can be shared across web servers. The problem is that no matter the configuration I pass in, it assumes that the url is localhost instead of the IP address I am providing. This is my code:

```
require 'uri'
require 'dragonfly'
require 'rack/cache'
require 'redis-store'
require 'redis-rack-cache'

### The dragonfly app ###
app = Dragonfly[:images]
app.configure_with(:rails)
app.configure_with(:imagemagick)

### Extend active record ###
app.define_macro(ActiveRecord::Base, :image_accessor)
app.define_macro(ActiveRecord::Base, :file_accessor)

### Insert the middleware ###
rack_cache_already_inserted = Rails.application.config.action_controller.perform_caching && Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.rack_cache

Rails.application.middleware.insert 0, Rack::Cache, {
  :verbose     => Rails.env.development?,
  :metastore   => "redis://SOMEIP:SOME_PORT/0/metastore", # URI encoded in case of spaces
  :entitystore => "redis://SOMEIP:SOME_PORT/0/entitystore",
} unless rack_cache_already_inserted

Rails.application.middleware.insert_after Rack::Cache, Dragonfly::Middleware, :images
```

No matter what I put instead of SOMEIP:SOME_PORT that value is ignored and it connects to redis on localhost.

Any ideas?

(Using Rails 3.0.10)